# bash expression to get the jira key out of git commit

Tags: regex, shell, curl, jenkins, jira

I have below code in my jenkins configuration in Execute Shell

```
jira_key=$(curl --request GET "http://jenkins-server/job/myProject/job/mySubProject/job/myComponent/${BUILD_NUMBER}/api/xml?xpath=/*/changeSet/item/comment" | sed -e "s/<comment>\(.*\)<\/comment>/\1/")
```

The result of the above command is

```
jira_key=<comment>JRA-1011 This is commit 
         message.
         </comment>
```

I am not sure how I can improve the above expression so that  start and end tags are excluded from the result.

However my ultimate goal is to extract the jira key which is the first word in the comment i.e. JRA-1011 and store it in jira_key. Once the  tags are excluded I can then get the first word by this command

```
set -- $jira_key
jira_key=$1
```

Is there any other better way to do this?

The xml is

```
<freeStyleBuild _class="hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild">
    <changeSet _class="hudson.plugins.git.GitChangeSetList">
        <item _class="hudson.plugins.git.GitChangeSet">
            <comment>
                JRA-1011 This is commit 
                message.
            </comment>
        </item>
    </changeSet>
</freeStyleBuild>
```

Comment: I think you can change the regex to:

s/<comment>\([\S]+\)[^<]+<\/comment>/\1/    if that does it, I'll write up a better explanation

Comment: Seems there is some escape sequence missing because when I put it between double quotes it shows diff color from [^<]+<\/comment>/\1/

Comment: interesting! we can just try escaping all kinds of stuff :)     s/<comment>\\([\S]+\\)[^<]+<\/comment>/\1/      shouldn't have to escape the parans but give that a shot

Comment: if I insert backward slash \ after + it doesn't complain, let me see what result it gives

Comment: I suspect it's something specific with sed that we are just not seeing, the regex itself, I think, should be pretty straightforward

Comment: got this error: sed: -e expression #1, char 38: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: hm!  sounds like it's not matching what is in the parans.  Try taking the \ off of the (   and   )       What might be helpful is just trying matching something like   s/<(c)omment>/\1/  and see if it swaps out the <comment> for c and then build the regex up from there.